# CABasicAnimation used for a chronometer animation doesn't work with iOS 8+

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, cabasicanimation

Some year ago i have used this code for realize a chronometer animation.
Was a cute animation but doesn't work with iOS8>

A circle should appears and lose a pie every 0.1sec but The animation doesn't start. It works on my iPhone 5 iOS 7.1

I tried to solve it but after 2 hours i have no solution.

Can someone with more experience with CABasicAnimation help me?

THANK YOU.

This is the code:

```
    //Animazione CRONOMETRO
-(void) startCronometro{

    //SetTime
    counterStart = TIME;

    [sfondoCronometro setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cronoStart.png"]];

    maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    CGFloat maskHeight = sfondoCronometro.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat maskWidth = sfondoCronometro.frame.size.width;


    CGPoint centerPoint;
    centerPoint = CGPointMake(sfondoCronometro.frame.size.width/2, (sfondoCronometro.frame.size.height/2));

    //Make the radius of our arc large enough to reach into the corners of the image view.
    CGFloat radius = sqrtf(maskWidth * maskWidth + maskHeight * maskHeight)/2;

    //Don't fill the path, but stroke it in black.
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    maskLayer.lineWidth = 25;

    CGMutablePathRef arcPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //Move to the starting point of the arc so there is no initial line connecting to the arc
    CGPathMoveToPoint(arcPath, nil, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y-radius/2);

    //Create an arc at 1/2 our circle radius, with a line thickess of the full circle radius
    CGPathAddArc(arcPath, nil, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius/2, 3*M_PI/2, -M_PI/2, NO);

    maskLayer.path = arcPath;//[aPath CGPath];//arcPath;

    //Start with an empty mask path (draw 0% of the arc)
    maskLayer.strokeEnd = 0;

    CFRelease(arcPath);

    //Install the mask layer into out image view's layer.
    sfondoCronometro.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    //Set our mask layer's frame to the parent layer's bounds.
    sfondoCronometro.layer.mask.frame = sfondoCronometro.layer.bounds;

    //Create an animation that increases the stroke length to 1, then reverses it back to zero.
    CABasicAnimation *swipe = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    swipe.duration = TIME;
    NSLog(@"TIME: %f", swipe.duration);
    swipe.delegate = self;
    // [swipe setValue:@"string" forKey:@"key"];
    swipe.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    swipe.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    swipe.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    swipe.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0];

    [maskLayer addAnimation: swipe forKey: @"strokeEnd"];

}
```

Comment: You said "...doesn't work with iOS8>" but didn't say *what* doesn't work. You posted a bunch of code, but with no explanation. What happens that you don't expect, or doesn't happen that you *do* expect? (Specifically.)

Comment: Yes, pardon moi. A circle should appears and lose a pie every 0.1sec but The animation doesn't start. It works on my iPhone 5 iOS 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to remember that at some point the function of CGPathAddArc changed, and depending on the values of your start and end angle, you had to flip the clockwise flag on the call. Try using clockwise = YES.

I just did a little testing in an app of mine and confirmed this. For the angles you're using, clockwise NO works for iOS <= 7, but fails for iOS >=8.

Switch the last parameter from NO to YES.